# String for both Apex Class and Javascript

Tags: apex, javascript

I am creating a `dynamic query` string for `SOQL`. Currently it is working fine as I am using `database.query()`.

For example : `string soqlStr = 'select Id, Name From Account where Name = \'Test\'';`

```
database.query(soqlStr);
```

But, I want to use the same string in java script to call `sforce.connection.query();`

But, it seems the Javascript is not accepting the `soqlStr` format, because of `where Name = \'Test\''`.

We can use `document.getElementById()` in `javascript`, but our search page has multiple filter criteria.

is there any other solution where we can use the same soql string for both `class` and `Javascript`.

Comment: And how are you constructing the string in javascript? Not sure why you thought a question about your javascript would be appropriate without actually posting what you are doing in JS......

Comment: @Eric : I am trying to reuse the soqlStr (which i created in class) in JavaScript.
soqlStr is merge valriable in my class.

Comment: `{!JSENCODE(soqlStr)}`

Comment: no problem‌​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‍​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​‍​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​